# How to Automatically delete files from NAS Server

Tags: network-attached-storage

We have a security camera in our office that saves video files in a NAS Server. These video files are occupying a lot of storage. I am looking a way to delete these files automatically which are older than x number of days.

Comment: What protocols does this NAS offer?  Could you mount the FS via NFS (or if you must, SMBFS) to a local server, and use cron to do the job?

Comment: We always use web browser to access the data. Its using HTTP protocol.

Comment: What protocol do you use to *write* the files in the first place?

Comment: Some NAS systems come with [specific](http://www.synology.com/en-uk/surveillance/index) [software](http://www.qnap.com/en/index.php?lang=en&sn=6855) to manage security camera's for you...

Comment: @HBruijn Yes we have a specific (Synology DSM 3.2) one. Can I some how achieve what I want ?

Comment: @Kami Synology DSM 3.2 sounds pretty old my own is running on DSM 4 and 5 is the current standard. For me surveillance station ss an optional package that can be installed from the package centre --> security tab

Comment: @HBruijn I cannot see the package "Surveillance Station" in the package list. Is there any possibility of Crontab some how?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? This command can be cronned:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14731180/696680

Be carefull that you still need to find *.avi (or whatever your extension is) files AND that you will need to do a "cd [path]" first!